# Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator'>, <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I tried data augmentation for a CNN but getting an error "Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator'>, <class 'NoneType'>". Can anyone please help me?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
(x_train, y_train) , (x_test, y_test) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()
img_width, img_height, img_num_channels = 32, 32, 3
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')       
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255.0              
x_test /= 255.0
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, img_num_channels)

CNN used
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, rotation_range=45, shear_range=0.2, 
                                   zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=100)

batch_size=100

model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = 2000 //batch_size, epochs =2,
                    validation_data = validation_datagen,
                    validation_steps = 800 //batch_size)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test) 
print('Test loss:', score[0]) 
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
predictions = model.predict([x_test])
#print(predictions)

print(np.argmax(predictions[0]))

img_path = x_test[0]
print(img_path.shape)
if(len(img_path.shape) == 3):
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(img_path))
elif(len(img_path.shape) == 2):
    plt.imshow(img_path)
else:
    print("Image cannot be shown")
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't define validation generator. Add this:

```
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow(x_test, y_test, batch_size=100)
```

and in training:

```
model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                steps_per_epoch = 2000 //batch_size, epochs =2,
                validation_data = validation_generator, #change this
                validation_steps = 800 //batch_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

do as noted in the answer by Kaveh. In addition you a rescaling the pixels twice. so remove

```
x_train /= 255.0              
x_test /= 255.0
```